# spark: group by unchanged sequence

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataset that looks kinda like this:

```
|---------------------|
|      Status         |
|---------------------|
|          1         |
|---------------------|
|          1         |
|---------------------|
|          2         |
|---------------------|
|          3         |
|---------------------|
|          3         |
|---------------------|
|          2         |
|---------------------|
|          2         |
|---------------------|
|          2         |
|---------------------|
|          1         |
|---------------------|
|          1         |
|---------------------|
```

I need to group each set of statuses that contain the same value in one row, what's the best way to do this in spark (version 2.2.4)

Comment: `df.distinct` will keep one row for each value

Answer (score -1):

You can **`groupBy`** on status then use `collect_list`

---

**`Example:`**

```
//sampledata

df.show()
//+------+
//|status|
//+------+
//|     1|
//|     1|
//|     2|
//|     3|
//|     3|
//|     2|
//|     1|
//+------+

df.groupBy("status").
agg(concat_ws(",",collect_list("status")).alias("group")).
show()   
//+------+-----+
//|status|group|
//+------+-----+
//|     3|  3,3|
//|     1|1,1,1|
//|     2|  2,2|
//+------+-----+

//collect as array

df.groupBy("status").
agg(collect_list("status").alias("group")).
show()  
//+------+---------+
//|status|    group|
//+------+---------+
//|     3|   [3, 3]|
//|     1|[1, 1, 1]|
//|     2|   [2, 2]|
//+------+---------+
```